# Using relatedTo, and/or and :empty/:notempty in queries

Tags: users, relations, queries

I got users that has 3 Entries fields in their profile: breadForMonday, breadForWednesday and breadForFriday.

I want to differentiate between users with 1, 2 or 3 selected entries. How would I use relatedTo together with and/or and :empty/:notempty?

Something like this:

```
{% set bread = craft.entries({ section: 'bread' }).limit(null) %}
{# Find users that have selected entries for two out of three fields #}
{% set users = craft.users({
    group: 'customers',
    relatedTo: [
        'and',
        { targetElement: bread, field: 'breadForMonday' },
        { targetElement: bread, field: 'breadForWednesday' }
    ]
}) %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please don't laugh, but I thought to myself, let's give this a go in Twig and see where it takes me.
It very soon began to become clear, that this will end up in lots of criteria models, db queries and a huge pile of Twig code.

So my better answer should be, don't do it in Twig. This is something you should better do in PHP with
custom database queries (→ [Yii query builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder)). But now that I've done it, here's [a gist](https://gist.github.com/carlcs/adbb84b5521f7d010c8e) of that Twig code.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put that together. I was worried that it will involve clunky Twig code, and was thinking about reducing it into a plugin. Got an example on how to do this with the query builder?

Comment: Unfortunatelly there's only very few examples here on Stack Exchange. This might help: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/7175 or this one: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/4600.